# Is there an advantage to using very specific selectors in CSS?

Tags: css, optimization, browser, css-selectors

I understand that in jQuery, it's advantageous to be more specific when using selectors so that jQuery doesn't have to traverse the entire DOM to find what you're looking for. For example, `$('span.description')` is better than just `$('.description')` if I know that the `description` class is only ever applied to `<span>` elements.

Is this the case with CSS, too? Is there any specific advantage for me to use `span.description { }` instead of `.description { }`? I'm thinking in terms of speed, optimization, etc. Am I saving the browser any work by telling it exactly where to look?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is true in CSS -

A good rule  is to descend from the nearest ID. 
IDs are indexed so locating them is extremely fast. There is no reason to use more than one in your selector.

**[Google Code- Optimize browser rendering](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html)**

This answered a lot of questions I had on the subject including this one-
I hope you find it useful.

Comment: I'll note that optimizing your CSS is probably not going to yield the same level of performance gains as optimizing your JS. Still I think keeping these things in mind is a very good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the info/link and not just telling me what specificity is. :)

Comment: "A good rule is to descend from the nearest ID". An even better rule is to not use descendant selectors at all but use classes instead. It's important to understand that browsers evaluate selectors from right to left, meaning that ´#foo img´ will start by finding every ´img´in the DOM and then traverse up in the DOM tree to see if the rest of the selector is satisfied.

Comment: This answer is misleading. It implies that descending from an id selector (e.g., `#id span`) is performant, when in actuality (as the linked article says), it's the "key selector", or right-most selector, that has the most profound impact on selector performance.

Answer (score 2):

Read up on css specificity - which is the most important reason to be more or less specific with your css.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

As browser performance is pretty much a non-issue (except for in jquery, as you've mentioned), my guideline is to be specific when you are controlling precedence, or when you want to make something a bit more readable in your css. Over specifying can make it tricky to re-use css selectors and make things overly complicated.

**Edit**

This looks like a bit of a duplicate:

[CSS Performance Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999463/css-performance-question)

Comment: I know all about this already. What I'm interested in is speed.

Comment: In my reading the speed gains are so marginal that it's not worth the time to consider.

Comment: @ScottE They are **not** marginal if you're dealing with large HTML documents, especially on slower / older devices. Code optimisation is always welcome.

Answer (score 1):

it always depends on your amount of html code and the structure. It is definitely a good idea to use especially ids and appropriate selectors. (ie #nav li  instead of li.nav). Since browser first load the html and then apply the css you are helping a lot.

This said, when it comes to pure css (no jquery) the difference in speed is nowadays not easy to distinguish, because the rendering engines are highly optimized - especially when it comes to applying css. So normally it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, how specific your selectors are make very little difference on the performance.

The two areas where more specific selectors are most useful, is to reduce the risk that it's not applied where you don't want it, and to make one selector take precedence over another.

Answer (score -1):

A more specific rule has precedence over a less specific rule, so:

```
span.myclass {}
```

has precedence over:

```
.myclass {}
```

(no matter what the order is in which the rules were declared)

Comment: I'm aware of that. What I'm interested in is whether there is a speed argument here.

Comment: I would be very surprised if it made any difference at all