# Problematic to use the child selector (>) in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am not sure if I remember correctly, but I think I read once that using the > selector in css rules was bad practice? Can someone shed some light on this topic?

For example:

```
<style>
#search-form {
 ... whatever rules...
}
#search-form > input[type=text] {
 ... rules...
}
#search-form > button {
 ... rules ...
}
</style>
<form id="search-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    <button>Search!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: [`>` is a tool](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors). Like any tool, if used incorrectly or improperly or inaccurately or with a lack of understanding, results may be unexpected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly not bad practice, but should be used with knowledge of the benefits and disadvantages. Using the child selector (`E > F`) will select only immediate children and, since this prevents complete descendant traversal, will take the browser less time to apply then a descendant selector (`E F`). However, the element isn't supported in IE6, so if that matters to you, steer clear.

This has a good write up and some nice links: [CSS child vs descendent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581000/css-child-vs-descendent-selector)

Answer (score 1):

The `>` selector is not supported in IE6, so if you need to support that old browsers you can't use it.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2

Other than that, there is no reason not to use it.

Comment: That could certainly be where the idea came from (based on old advice).

Answer (score 1):

The child selector matches only the immediate descendant of the left-side selector. It may, or may not be what you want, but applying a certain style for all descendants, regardless of how deep under the left-side selector they are, is more common.

With e.g. `#mydiv > span` ask yourself: do I really not want to match a `span` within a `p` under `#mydiv`. What about a `span` in a `li` within `#mydiv`? Etc. Maybe you don't -- maybe you do. The important part is to [understand what it does](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_child.htm).