# What is the difference (and advantage, if any) of using ">" in css selectors?

Tags: html, css, web

Here are two examples of css selectors and I can't tell what the difference is and therefore, which one should be used in which cases:

```
.foo-class a{
    /* this will select all anchor tags inside foo-classes */
}

.foo-class > a{
    /* this will also select all anchor tags inside foo-classes, no? */
}
```

EDIT: I just found the answer. ">" only selects direct children. I'll leave the question up here in case others find it useful.

Comment: it's known as combinator - http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/combinators

Answer (score 10):

`>` means select only a direct child of `foo-class`. If you use the first selector, it will select a child at any level under `foo-class`. In the code below, using `>` will mean that the first anchor is not selected, because it's not a direct descendant of `foo-class` however the second one would be.

```
<div class="foo-class">
    <p>
        <a href="#">Unaffected Link</a>
    </p>
    <a href="#">Affected Link</a>
</div>
```

There's no "advantage", it's just a different way to control what you select.

Comment: I've also read there are some performance advantages.  Meaning, if you *can* use `>` then you should.

Comment: @MikeChristensen None of serious consideration that I am aware of. The relatively refined selectors that bound it (`.foo-class`, `a`) should keep it well-behaved.

Comment: @MikeChristensen their functionality is completely different, so performance is less of a concern here. You should only use `>` when you want that specific functionality.

Comment: I've seen this stated in various blogs, and also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581000/css-child-vs-descendent-selector) StackOverflow question.

Comment: Imagine a huge dom. If the browsers knows to look no further than the direct child, even though the element had thousands of children. Of course it will be faster. But i highly doubt that you would feel the difference. There are far more important things to consider for performance. But personally i think it's good practice.

Comment: CSS gets evaluated right to left, so the amount of children `foo-class` has doesn't matter, rather, the path from the `a` to the root, because the `a` is found first.

Answer (score 1):

Second one is the direct a child of the `.foo-class`. The first one is every a inside `.foo-class`

Comment: This isn't very useful and already covered below.